# Smartsheet API User Level

Tags: smartsheet-api

For Smartsheet API oauth flow, is the access token that is generated scoped for the user only? Or is it scoped for the entire account? I thought that the token is account scoped until I tried to use the "comment" api here: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#comments, where it seems there is no way of specifying which user left the comment. Does that mean that every user has to perform their own oauth?

Answer (score 0):

A Smartsheet access token obtained via OAuth is indeed scoped to the user who performed the OAuth process. In fact, regardless of whether a user is accessing Smartsheet data via API (either directly or via OAuth) or via the Smartsheet UI -- the user will always only be able to access data according to their current access level and permissions in Smartsheet. There's no such thing as an "admin" user or token that can access any and all data throughout the entire Smartsheet account.